# How can I change the background color of an EditText when text is entered using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

Just to be clear, I want to change the color of the textField to be clear once text is entered and for it to go back to its old color, which in my case is gray when it has no text. I looked through stackoverflow and found some answers, however it was in Java and I am still a beginner with Kotlin, but I am writing this in Kotlin for my work.

Essentially, I want to know how can you change the background of the textField once text is entered?

[image]

I want to have the background color of that to change once text is entered using Kotlin.

This is my XML EditText that I am referring to:

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/addImage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/addImage"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/description"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Where do I go from here now?

```
class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var button: Button
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var editText: EditText


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)

    editText = findViewById(R.id.description)

}
}
```

This is just what I have on my activity. I don't have any method really on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a TextWatcher to react when text has been changed.

```
val originalColor = (editText.background as ColorDrawable).color // or Color.LIGHT_GRAY
val haveTextColor = Color.TRANSPARENT // or whatever you want
editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            editText.setBackgroundColor(if (s.isEmpty()) originalColor else haveTextColor)
        }

    })
```

Comment: What is the purpose all of those integers?

Comment: You can use those callbacks to intercept changes to the string before they’re committed. Those are indices of which characters are changing and how many are changing. More than one character can change at a time of the user has selected multiple characters and begins typing or uses the paste function.

Comment: Understanding. I have a type mismatch on the last line with the editText.setBackgroundColor(if (s.isEmpty()) ..... you can fill in the rest. I am not sure what I would do to change that...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there is no `backgroundColor` getter for Views. The color should be an Int. See update. If you want to read about how Colors are interpreted as 32 bit integers on Android, read about Color ints here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color

Comment: Is there a possible way to have the background change color, but keep the borders visible?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by borders. Views don't have a border property. You can give them a background drawable instead of color and that drawable can be an outlined rectangle. Or, probably easier, you could put the text view inside a FrameLayout that has padding of 1 or 2 dp to create the appearance of a border while still being able to change the text view's background color. But that wouldn't look right if you want rounded corners.

Comment: I don't want rounded corners. I want like a black line that outlines the editText field once the color changes. The only issue I have is that I already have the android:background="" set to gray, therefore, I don't know how I can use another background twice since I get an error when I try to do that.

Comment: I already have a drawable that does that. I just don't know how I will implement it because I do want the gray background too.

Comment: I will most likely just ask a separate question on how to do that if I can't figure it out soon.

Comment: I recommend making two background shape drawables, one with each color, and set those as the background instead of setting a color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `doAfterTextChanged` Kotlin extension function here. It can be used to perform some action every time the text changes.

```kotlin
editText.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
    editText.setBackgroundColor(if (text.isEmpty()) color1 else color2) // Choose whatever colors you want
}
```

Comment: Is the text suppose to be the id of the editText that I am working on? What exactly is text suppose to represent?

Comment: The CharSequence in the edit text.